# MongoMapper "save(:safe => true)" throws "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a simple MongoMapper model:

```
class Author
    include MongoMapper::Document
    key :name, String
end
```

And this works fine:

```
a = Author.new(:name => 'Alice')
a.save                              # => returns 'true'
```

Now I want to use the `:safe` option as described at http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/safe.html:

> Instead of just using the default “fire and forget” behavior on our
>   save operation, passing the :safe option to save will force the driver
>   to make sure the save succeeds and raise an error if it doesn’t.

So I try:

```
a = Author.new(:name => 'Bob')
a.save(:safe => true)               # => throws exception
```

This throws "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" ... "in `save'". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using MongoMapper 0.11.1. I checked the local installed gem files, and the Safe plugin is included by default.

Comment: What version of MongoMapper are you using?

Comment: @Intelekshual, sorry, should have included that originally. Version 0.11.1. Updated question to include that info.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with 0.11.1.